# Process to secure my REST API with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in process to design an application for a customer where the User Interface will be in Angular 6 and the back-end will be in the API.Now as I am using angular (SPA) I communicate with server though JSON and REST API. Now need your suggestions on the process to secure my API.

My Analysis -

1) [Personal Access Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens) is not a good idea as the tokens are always long lived. I have already done a demo on the same.

2) [Consuming Your API With JavaScript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) is may be a good option but it used cookies and it will be good approach or not I am not sure.

I am open for any good suggestions including other approach like JWT also if it's proves logical.

Thans in Advance.

Comment: This open-ended, opinion-based type of question is not really appropriate on SO, and it is likely to be closed.  See [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what's off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [this linked question about suggestion/recommendation questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `Laravel - Passport`. Its is a build in system  in `laravel` framework. So you can get user personal token and save it in your `local storage`. 
There is a lot of way to secure you `RESTful` api , but before that you need to understand exactly which systems will interact with you api.

Comment: WIth my API only my oqn developed mobile application and web project will interact. Now in passport multiple approaches are there. So, which approach will be better like 2 approaches are mentioned in the Question already

Comment: I dont suggest you to use cookie because the cookie is editable for users , also that is not recomended to save user state in browser. the person access token are not *always long lived*. you can set the duration and update expiration if you need

Comment: I think 'Password Grant Tokens' is the best option for my solution. But I don't want to share the client id and secret with my local applications. So, is it possible that user name and password  to be send by the web app then after receiving the same in laravel controller I will fire a post request from the controller only with the client id and secret.

Lastly will it uses the user model to fetch the records because I have updated the user model as per my requirement.

Comment: Also personal access tokens are long lived and time can not be changed as per laravel documentations.

Comment: Hey I have implemented the OAUTH with grant option and it's working as expected. Just one more question out of context of oauth. In normal project we have middle ware to validate all request (As per configuration), Controller to handle all the request and Model to connect with database. But how I can manage the service layer where I will right my business logic like what processing needed before sending the data. Is laravel have any option to support the same.